# Replace backward slashes with forwards slashes or double backward slashes in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

So I have a string:

```
string path = "C:\Users\Richard\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Client\Debug";
```

I want to replace all backward slashes in it with forward ones so it looks like:

```
C:/Users/Richard/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/Client/Debug
```

This does not work:

```
string toReplace = "\\";
path.replace(path.find(toReplace), toReplace.length(), "/");
```

Obviously, \ is an escape character so that is probably causing the problem.

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I get a compiler error on your `path` string with g++, since it contains invalid escape codes. Apparently, MSVC produces warnings but no errors for that (see Michael Burr's answer). So if you are really using the `path` you have posted, change the backslashes to double backslashes.

Correcting that, I find that your code replaces only the first backslash and leaves the others. Maybe you want to use `std::replace()`, like so:

```
std::replace(path.begin(), path.end(), '\\', '/');
```

Comment: I don't think that will work.  `std::replace` will look for the \ character, but it won't find any in the string because the compiler will interpret each \ to be an escape character for the letter after it.

Comment: @Maxpm, this answer is the best way to do a find/replace of a single character.  But it should be noted that the actual string provided by the OP needs to be escaped properly for this to work.

Comment: My install of GCC (MinGW with GCC 4.5.1) with whatever options I have set up in my script for invoking g++ (-Wall probably being the only one that matters) only considers the invalid  `\U` escape sequence here an error.  All the other ones are just warnings.  VC considers them all warnings.

Comment: @Michael Burr: I get "incomplete universal character name" on the \U, and "unknown escape sequence" on the rest. All errors. This is g++ 4.3.2 on Debian with `-Wall` and `-Wextra`.

Comment: @Fred: either gcc changed the severity of "unknown escape sequence" between 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 from a warning to an error, or maybe you also have `-Werror` which makes all warnings an error?

Comment: since std::replace(path.begin(), path.end(), '\\', '/'); replace only one character, will running it twice work?

Comment: `std::replace` should replace all occurrences.

Answer (score 9):

If you have something like this:

```
string path = "C:\Users\Richard\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Client\Debug";
```

it every character proceded by '\' is special character. The correct way is

```
string path = "C:\\Users\\Richard\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\Client\\Debug";
```

Use std::replace like Fred said.

Answer (score 2):

Is the "string path = ..." in your source file as shown?  If so, then there are no backslashes to replace.

The following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string path = "C:\Users\Richard\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Client\Debug";

    cout << path;
}
```

Outputs:

```
C:UsersRichardDocumentsVisual Studio 2010ProjectsClientDebug
```

---

Note: the above program compiles (with a bunch of warnings) in MSVC (through VS2010), but with GCC 4.5.1 I get an error:

```
C:\temp\test.cpp:8:19: error: incomplete universal character name \U
```

The behavior of MSVC for this error (or GCC for that matter) might be configurable with appropriate options.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there's no way to do this from the string you specified.  Your code is trying to escape the characters `U`, `R`, `D`, `V`, `P`, etc.

If the string is hard-coded, you'll have to use double-slashes (i.e., `C:\\Users\\Richard...`).

If the string is a path that, say, the user enters, you might be able to add the escape characters programmatically.

Comment: If the string is user input, then you won't need to escape anything.

Answer (score -1):

Try using string.findfirsof('\');